# Is there a CSS workaround for Firefox' bug: inline-block + first-letter with changed size

Tags: css, firefox

It's better to see a bug for yourself in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/btdVd/

The picture, showing the bug:

[image]

And the bug [filled in 2007 on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385615).

The bug appears when you're adding `::first-letter` pseudo-element with `display: inline-block`, and then change the `font-size` of this `first-letter`.

More letters in a word after the first: more extra space added (or subtracted — if the font-size is lesser than block's).

Adding `float: left` to the `first-letter` inverts the bug: with bigger font-size the width of `inline-block` shrinks.

So, the question: is there any CSS-only workaround for this bug? It's somewhat killing me.

Comment: This is still a bug. I added another solution that I think is simpler, using `-moz-padding-end`.

Comment: Thanks. We ran into this EXACT bug today.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found that triggering reflow on the whole page (or any block with a problem) fixes the problem, so I've found a way to trigger it on every such block with one-time CSS animation: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/btdVd/23/

Still, while this fix have no downsides in rendering, it have some other ones:

- it would work only for Fx5+ (that supports animations);
- it still flashes the original bug for a few ms, so it's maybe somewhat blinky.

So, it's not an ideal solution, but would somewhat help when Fx4- would be outdated. Of course, you can trigger such fix onload with JS, but it's not that nice.

Comment: Since there were no better answers and Fx4- are somewhat old, using the animation here is the best solution so far.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's a good solution.

I have come up with a flaky solution for you though:

```
.test:first-letter {
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: -0.225em;
}
```

Add the `letter-spacing` style to the `:first-letter` selector in your Fiddle, and you'll find the blocks go back to *roughly* the right size.

**Explanation:**

Basically, the bug is being caused by the whole block taking its size from the font specified in the `first-letter`.

What I'm doing here with the `letter-spacing` is trying to adjust the size of this font, without affecting it's physical appearance. Adjusting the letter spacing in this way in normal text would result in the letters overlapping each other by .225 of a character width on either side.

I was initially hoping that a value of -0.25 would be sufficient -- ie a quarter of a character on each side would reduce the width of each character by half, which would be what we want because the first letter is `font-size:2em`, so it's twice as big.

However, the calculation isn't quite as clean as that, because the first and last characters in the string would only be overlapped on one side each, and because the first letter does in fact want to be double width, even if the rest of the characters don't.

All of this means that the exact `letter-spacing` value required to counter-act the bug will vary depending on how long the text, as well as the font sizes of the original text and the first letter. This is why I had to experiment a bit with the value of the letter spacing to get it working, and also explains why I couldn't get quite a perfect fit on all the text rows in your Fiddle. I would have needed a slightly different value for each block.

The value of -0.225 seems to be about the closest I can get to it being right for all your examples, but in practice you'll need to adjust it to suit your site.

Don't forget also that this is a Firefox bug, and therefore you'll need to write it in as a browser-specific hack of some sort. And be careful to keep an eye on the Firefox bug report you linked; when it does get fixed, you'll need to work out a way to keep your hack in place for users of old versions, but remove it for users with the fix.

[EDIT]

The only other working solution I've come up with is simply not to use the features which trigger the bug. ie drop the `:first-letter` selector, and use a separate `<span>` for the first letter of your text if you want to style it differently.

This is the obvious answer really, and would of course solve the problem (and would also mean that your styled first letter works in older browsers), but it would not be ideal from a semantic perspective, and more importantly doesn't actually answer the question, which is why I didn't offer it as a solution in my original answer.

I have been trying to find alternative work around for the bug as well, but the options are limited, and nothing I've tried has given as good results as my initial suggestion.

I tried a hack of making the `:first-letter` invisible, and using `:before` to display the big leading capital letter. However, this didn't work for me. I didn't linger on it too long so you may be able to get it working, but there is a problem with it in that you'd have to define the leading letter in your CSS, which wouldn't be ideal.

Another possible solution is to use the CSS `font-stretch: condensed;` property on the `:first-letter`. This would reduce the width of the first letter back to `1em`, and thus resolve the width issue of the rest of the text. The down sides of this, however, are that firstly it would make the leading letter look squashed, which is probably not what you want, and secondly this style only works for fonts which support the `condensed` property. It turns out that this isn't well supported by the standard fonts, so may not be workable for you.

In the end, the original `letter-spacing` solution is still the only way I've found to really work around the bug.

Comment: Vote up for explanation. Sad, but I need a more stable fix, that'd work for short and long words and for different first chars: seems, that the `letter-spacing` must be different for, for example, `W` and `I` letters. Also, the negative letter-spacing itself isn't look good anyway :(

Comment: I know it's not perfect, but sadly this is as close as I've been able to get to counter-acting the effect of the bug. The only other solution I can give is give up trying to use the `:first-letter` selector, and split out the first letter into its own `<span>`. Its not ideal, not semantic, and doesn't actually address the bug, but it would resolve the issue for your page.

Comment: @kizu - I've added some notes on a few other ideas I tried for solving this issue.

Comment: Yeah, the one with extra block for first-letter is 100% fix, but it's just the place where I wanted to use the not-so-often-used `:first-letter` and couldn't :( Also, I found another way to handle this bug: triggering the reflow on the block. But for Fx4- it's useless without JS.

Comment: Just sayin', `compressed` doesn't exist. It's `condensed`.

Answer (score 0):

This bug still exists, but some of the fixes don't work anymore. Even after triggering a reflow with an animation, the inline-block returned to the same size for me. I couldn't use the `letter-spacing` trick because I am already using it on the first letter, that is what is causing the problem for me. I solved the problem by adding this to the CSS for the affected selector:

```
-moz-padding-end: *number of pixels to compensate*;
```

At the moment, `moz-padding-end` seems to be specific to Firefox, and it can add or remove width to the end of the inline-block. Because this is a Firefox specific bug, that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old now, but apparently this bug has not been fixed yet.

Using `animation` does work but there is a noticeable FOUT (Flash Of Unstyled Text). I was able to work around the problem by wrapping the `first-letter` in a `span`. This does work around both the sizing issue and the FOUT, it does add extra elements to the markup, so it depends on the needs of your site/application if this is the best fit.

```css
.test {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15); /* For visualisation */
    display: inline-block;
}

.test:first-letter {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.test2:first-letter {
    float: left;
}
.test3:first-letter {
    font-size: .5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Inline-block with bigger first-letter</h1>

<span class="test">Broken</span>
<br><br>
<span class="test"><span>F</span>ixed</span>


<h1>+ floating to first-letter</h1>

<span class="test test2">Broken</span>
<br><br>
<span class="test test2"><span>F</span>ixed</span>
 

<h1>small size for first-letter</h1>

<span class="test test3">Broken</span>
<br><br>
<span class="test test3"><span>F</span>ixed</span>

<h1>small size, floating first-letter</h1>

<span class="test test2 test3">Broken</span>
<br><br>
<span class="test test2 test3"><span>F</span>ixed</span>
```

Comment: It should be noted that wrapping parts of words in spans can hurt accessibility, for example, VoiceOver would read this incorrectly. There are possible solutions with aria-label on the closest topmost element that would accept it, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, this is still happening in Firefox.
This is my solution using SASS, but you can see how to make it bare CSS:

```
txt-brand {
   display:inline-block;
}

///Firefox only ///
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
         margin-right: .1em;
         white-space: nowrap;

         &::after {
              content: '\00a0';
         }
    }
}

.txt-brand::first-letter {
    letter-spacing: -.11em;
}
```

Comment: For code we often use backticks instead of non-breaking space characters. Might save you a bit of time next answer 