# Firefox whitespace oddity bug on <a> element

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I have included a [link to a video](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B47tip0c_KEtN0s3YW5oUGRUQVE) describing this in depth but basically Firefox is adding left/right whitespace to the  element making the perceived padding different than Chrome and IE. If I modify the value in Firebug and change back then the whitespace is gone and works as I expect in the first place. This is very frustrating, any ideas?

Please watch [the video](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B47tip0c_KEtN0s3YW5oUGRUQVE) for an exact description.

Thanks

Update 1: Here is a test server you can inspect the code on, it may differ slightly from the video but the problem is still the same. [test.audrey-oxenhorn.gotpantheon.com](http://test.audrey-oxenhorn.gotpantheon.com)

Update 2: It appears to be the :first-letter pseudo element that FF has an issue with. I think this is an actual browser bug but am not sure how to resolve this right now.

Comment: Google Meyer reset or normalize.css You're experiencing browser default CSS settings throwing things off it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out!

After trial and error trying to recreate this on JSfiddle I found that the :first-letter pseudo element was causing the issue. Then I did some searching and found that this is a [known browser bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385615) that has been open since 2007. There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548255/is-there-a-css-workaround-for-firefox-bug-inline-block-first-letter-with-cha). Since I was able to correct the issue via triggering a reflow/redraw via Firebug I suspected that the issue was the same as the one previously mentioned and I used the following code to trigger the reflow on that block element:

```
@-moz-keyframes bugfix { from { padding-right: 1px ; } to { padding-right: 0; } }

.sf-menu a {
  -moz-animation: bugfix 0.001s;
}
```

Problem solved, I linked the bugzilla report to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to apply a CSS Master Reset. Which you may find here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Apply this at the beginning of your CSS Document. Or check your parent CSS Declarations. There may be a problem with inheritance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As an addition, if this does fix the problem, you won't need the entire reset. Probably just a reset on `a`, so `a { padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;`

Comment: @Andy: Indeed Andy, thank you! But it is always safe to roll with a full reset, so you don't run into the same problem for other elements as well.

Comment: I added the reset but it is not having any affect. Worth mentioning is that there is already a reset being applied earlier in the cascade as part of the dgo.to/omega theme for Drupal.

Comment: @ElijahLynn: Can you give us a link to the problem then?

Comment: Here is a test server you can inspect the code on (I think it is or is based on 960.gs reset.css), it may differ slightly from the video but the problem is still the same. http://test.audrey-oxenhorn.gotpantheon.com/

Comment: Here is the reset.css I am using for reference - http://drupalcode.org/project/omega.git/blob/7cf1cc554ea7fbb0a87cca2ec2c3ad973dd40638:/alpha/css/alpha-reset.css

Comment: @ElijahLynn: For the .sf-menu a style, change the padding to just be 1em. No 1.5em.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18864/discussion-between-elijah-lynn-and-aaron-brewer)

Comment: It appears to be the :first-letter pseudo element that FF has an issue with. I think this is an actual browser bug but am not sure how to resolve this right now.

Comment: Apologies for not figuring this one out sooner.