# css jquery position fixed element on the right. animate BUG in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I created a fiddle for my question:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88SZZ/)

```
$('#move').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).not('.up').animate({
        bottom: '50%'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).addClass('up');
    });

    $('.up').animate({
        bottom: '0%'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('up');
    });
});
```

There is a bug in Firefox (my version: 19.0.2).

When you click the red button, it jumps to the right (distance has exactly the width of the scrollbar).
when it is on the right and you resize the window (or fiddle-frame) it jumps back.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a good solution to fix it?

Comment: If you know it's a bug, it's time to fill a bug report at mozilla.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a firefox bug or a jquery bug. because without the jquery part it's ok...

Comment: It works correctly in Chrome.

Comment: possibly related to this bug? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130653/firefox-calculating-blocks-larger/

Comment: don't think so. but how can i fix it?

Comment: Since firefox and chrome act differently, it must be a bug in one of them (most likely in the one that's failing). I wouldn't be surprised by yet another rendering bug in firefox. Try the same workaround as for the other bug - trigger a reflow.

Comment: what do you mean with trigger a reflow. how should that work? what should i trigger?

Comment: See the question I'm linking to. Try to see if triggering an unrelated animation fixes the render. If not, just do an animation that's not unrelated. I will investigate.

Comment: It is definitely a browser bug

Comment: I tried to fix it with this reflow-bugfix you said. but it doesn't work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/88SZZ/1/ if I resize the frame-window it still jumps

Comment: Perhaps you could just re-implement `fixed` via Javascript unless you know the browser can handle `fixed` properly (though feature-detection might be difficult)

Comment: @JanDvorak https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=844178

Answer (score 11, accepted):

well if you change the width property  then it works fine even on firefox

try this

change

```
width:100px
```

to

```
min-width:100px;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: definitely not a jQuery error, but may be something's fishy with firefox.