# CSS fixed position movement under scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

In Firefox (version 19.0.2) when positioning an element to the right of the page using `position: fixed` the element is positioned relative to the window viewport right of the window scrollbar.

However, on hover when we change the positioning values, the element is positioned relative to the window viewport not including the window scrollbar.

In the following example this causes the element to move from right of the scrollbar, to underneath the scrollbar on hover.

I have isolated the problem down to see that it is not caused by any other css settings set on `body`, `html` or anything else, but I cannot find the reason for this problem.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#Top" id="ScrollToTop">Top</a>
```

**CSS**

```css
#ScrollToTop {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}
#ScrollToTop:hover {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KxEUY/)**

Is there a reason this is occurring? Is this a browser bug? Is there a way to fix this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling, my solution would be to put the ScrollToTop anchor inside another fixed position div.

HTML

```
<div id="ScrollToTopHolder"><a href="#Top" id="ScrollToTop">Top</a></div>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    background: #990000;
}
#ScrollToTopHolder {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
}
#ScrollToTop {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
#ScrollToTop:hover {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVxPz/)

It seems to be that Firefox doesn't like it when you move the fixed anchor position, re-aligning it.

Comment: Just had a similar issue with a website. It only happens in Firefox since about v19.

Comment: what a garbagy browser ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround was found, use min-width instead of width for the fixed position div: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705522/980692