# Firefox, position fixed, scroll bar

Tags: jquery, css, fixed

In this example If I animate the div red it makes a strange movement to the right. I think the problem comes only with Firefox, the div is right, there is a scroll bar and position fixed.

(If I use position absolute I solve the movement. But If the user scrolls, the div moves, and it should be "fixed" to the right, bottom)

- Firefox
- Right
- Scroll bar
- Fixed position

Please check it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LhAEh/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#red {
    position: fixed; /* fixed genera el problema */ 
    bottom: 20px; right:25px;
    width:80px; height:50px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    background:red;
}

#blue {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80px; height:500px;
    background:blue;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#red").click(function() {
        $("#red").animate({bottom:'-80px'},1000);
    }); 
})
```

[image: Original position]
[image: After click]

- Image 1: Original position
- Image 2: When someone clicks it moves right and then down. It should only moves down

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue happening and also how you want it to behave? As I checked in FireFox, IE10 and chrome, but all the three version are getting the same behavior of the Div red which is making it to fall down on click.

Comment: When you click red it moves to the right and then goes down. (I think it compensates the scroll bar) It should go down, without moving to the right. I check it in Firefox 20.0. (I think last one). Now, I see that in an old Firefox 3.6 It does not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a workaround was found, change the fixed box's position to absolute and put it inside another fixed position div:
[CSS fixed position movement under scrollbar in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779203/css-fixed-position-movement-under-scrollbar-in-firefox)

Also, there is an open bug on this issue: [CSS position fixed no longer factors in scrollbar after hover](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=844178)

**UPDATE:** A better workaround was found, use min-width instead of width for the fixed box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705522/980692

Comment: Both solutions are very good. I do not understand why min-width, but it works!. Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CGkEU/2/

try this jsfiddle

```
.background{
    position:static;
}
```

Comment: It works! But I don't understand why. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: because your divs were on the html page it self and not the container "background". the page when changed size will get the vertical scroll bar which then pushes your div. in the static container the scroll bar does not affect the div.  relative container will move with the scroll bar

Comment: this might help you understand it a bit better - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp I am currently reading a book about HTML5 and CSS3 and finished the section about positioning, i understand it but if my explanation isn't good enough then follow the link, cheers

Comment: @Nrc, it seems that sander did 2 alteration to the original code, he added the above CSS and also added a JS line that on click changes the red div position from fixed to absolute, from what I've tested, the JS is what fixed the problem and not the CSS. But it created a new problem: if you scroll down and then click on the red then you notice the change from fixed to absolute position of the red box, it jumps up. so in conclusion, it seems that the problem was not solved.

Comment: If there is a scroll (because the screen is smaller than #blue) and then you click #red then it jumps. It must be a bug in Firefox and the 2 options of @benkol solve the problem. Anyway, your solution is quite close. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CGkEU/3/)

```
.background{
    position:relative;
}

$(function(){       
    $("#red").click(function() {
        $("#red").animate({bottom:'15px'},1000);
        $("#red").css({"position":"absolute","right":"15px"});
    });     
})
```

Comment: In your demo, red jumps. I think position absolute puts red in a different position than fixed. They are no equivalent

Comment: Make the screen smaller than the #blue and you will see that it jumps