# jQuery animate doesn't work correctly in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate

```
 jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('#rightbar').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                  jQuery(this).stop().animate({right: 0}, {duration:600});
            });
            jQuery('#rightbar').bind('mouseleave',function(){
                  jQuery(this).stop().animate({right: '-150px'}, {duration:600});
            });
        });
```

While I use this function on my website, it works correctly on all other browsers except firefox (latest).

When I hover on div #rightbar it move to left instead of move to right as my script.
I check on Chrome and frefox:

On Chrome, when hover, right attribute change from: -150 -> 0

But on firefox, when hover, right attribute change -150 -> -170 ...etc..

I don't know why, maybe it's firefox bug (?).

Look forward your help.

Thank you!

P/s: You can check here: http://goo.gl/SChFo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research and it looks like it is a bug in FireFox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=844178

You can fix it if you use `min-width` instead of `width` for your `.rightbar` (At least for firefox, but honestly I need to say that I did not have time right now to check if this would work cross browser)

Here a similar question having the same problem:
[css jquery position fixed element on the right. animate BUG in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15704727/1960455)

This question makes it more clear that it is a problem of FF, because there the `right` value is not touched but only the `bottom` value is changed, but with the same effect as in your example.

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt the `position` problem is fixed in ff 23 (beta).  So it is only version 19 to 22.