# Extra space in span with text-transform

Tags: css, firefox

I've notice that when applying

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

to an inline-block span, firefox adds a space at the end of the text. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/matias/kt71jkLz/

Also, if you switch on and off that css rule using firebug, firefox removes that space and never adds it again. Chrome doesn't add that space at all.

**HTML**

```
<span>Sample text</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span{display:inline-block; color: red; outline: 1px solid blue;}
span:first-letter{text-transform: uppercase;}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548255/is-there-a-css-workaround-for-firefox-bug-inline-block-first-letter-with-cha

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I ran into the same problem in one of my email campaigns and managed to solve it with a work-around.

In a : 
    paragraph

With something like this in the mobile CSS:

```
span[class=capital] {
    text-transform:uppercase !important;}
```

resulted in this displaying in the final email in Outlook after sending:

```
p aragraph
```

In FF locally it was fine at full-width and at responsive-width, but after the email was sent the space showed up in both versions (but with proper text-transform where appropriate).

In my case the solution was to wrap the entire word in the span rather than just the first letter and to change the text-transform to "capitalize".

```
span[class=capital] {
    text-transform:capitalize !important;}
```

This did not affect the following spacing after the word, e.g. no extra space.