# css first letter glitch in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

I encountered a CSS glitch in Firefox which works fine in IE and Chrome.
The following example shows multiple `a` tags which should all be the smallest size possible and the `a` tags with `.first-capitalized` should have their first letter capitalized. But the altering with the pseudo selector `::first-letter` destroys this behavior. Is there a css hack so it behaves like it does in Chrome and IE ?

(You can display the correct representation in Firefox, if you deactivate and reactive the `font-size` rule in the `.first-capitalized` selector set.)

```css
a{
  font-size: 14pt;
  display: inline-block;
}
.first-capitalized{
  font-size: 9pt;
}
.first-capitalized::first-letter{
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<a href="">LOREM</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">IPSUM</a>
<a href="">DOLOR</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">SIT</a>
<a href="">AMET</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">CONSETETUR</a>
<a href="">SADIPSCING</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">ELITR</a>
```

## Those fixen do not work reliable, after abou 20 refreshes they appear to lose their functionality!

EDIT:

I just wrote a "fix" in js which works just like the fix from [@LukyVi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427323/3647724)

```
var continueFlag = true;
for (var i = 0; continueFlag && i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    for (var n = 0; continueFlag && n < sheet.cssRules.length; n++) {
        var rule = sheet.cssRules[n];
        if (rule.selectorText == '.first-capitalized') {
            var orig = rule.style['font-size'];
            rule.style['font-size'] = '0px';
            continueFlag = false
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function (rule) {
                //font size = 0px gets rendered
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function (rule) {
                    //font size = orig gets rendered
                    rule.style['font-size'] = orig;
                }.bind(this, rule))
            }.bind(this, rule)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the elements with the first-letter pseudo element take up as much space as if the whole word had the larger font size. Then, when toggled in developer tools firefox fixes this (as OP mentions) Looks like a firefox bug to me

Comment: @Danield precisly what I though :( Do you have any ideas as to how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've found a small fix for your problem. 
Since the issue got fix on page repaint, you can just add a small keyframe to force the repaint.

It's really hacky, but it works. Until Firefox fix the issue. 
You can also decide to not use the `::first-letter` pseudo-element, and use something more "hard coded", like wrapping the first letter of your tag with a `<span>`.

That being said, I've searched for a solution to your problem for a while, and a similar StackOverflow post helped me to get to this solution ( this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553176/1331432 )

```css
a{
  font-size: 14pt;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: fix 0.00000001s;
}
.first-capitalized{
  font-size: 9pt;
  -moz-padding-end: 0;
  font-stretch: condensed;
}
.first-capitalized::first-letter{
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: red
}

@-moz-keyframes fix {
   from { padding-right: 1px; } 
   to { padding-right: 0; } 
}
```

```html
<a href="">LOREM</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">IPSUM</a>
<a href="">DOLOR</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">SIT</a>
<a href="">AMET</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">CONSETETUR</a>
<a href="">SADIPSCING</a>
<a href="" class="first-capitalized">ELITR</a>
```

Regards,

Lucas.

Comment: :D that is perfect, I had a similar idea and was building a solution with js. But yours is so much nicer! Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Glad if this helps :) But all the credits goes to http://stackoverflow.com/users/885556/kizu

Comment: Btw. I just added a js solution which is pretty similar to yours (or kizus).

Comment: 4 years later, this is still an issue.