# The font-size within a first-letter selector is dictating the width of the line box

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-size

```css
.Container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.Title {    
    font-size: 5rem;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.Word::first-letter {
    font-size: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>First-Letter Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Title">
            <div class="Word">Abcde</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm experiencing an issue where the width of a line box, is being dictated by the `font-size` of a `::first-letter` selector:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is for the line box to be the width that is actually required, while respecting the properties of the `::first-letter` selector - giving a border such as:

[image]

If you change the `font-size` of either the `.Title` to be as stated in the `.Word::first-selector`, then the width of the line box is as expected, but clearly the styling of the first letter is indistinguisable from the remainder of the text:

```
.Title {    
    font-size: 10rem;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

What am I missing to achieve this?

Comment: What browser are you using. I cannot replicate the problem on Safari/IOS.

Comment: Firefox 111.0.1 64-bit - this is the latest version as of writing.

Comment: can confirm it happens on Firefox, behaviour is pretty weird too, if I edit the value in the console the width gets recalculated correctly

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548255/is-there-a-css-workaround-for-firefox-bug-inline-block-first-letter-with-cha/7553176) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425083/css-first-letter-glitch-in-firefox) seems related

Comment: Hello @LS_. Thanks for confirmation and taking time to find the related questions - not sure how you managed to find them! Question is closed as per your request. Rather concerning the original bug is dated 2007! :S